# Easiest way to reindent / tidy Python code in Coda?

Tags: python, django, tidy, indentation, coda

Anyone have a clever way of quickly fixing indentation problems in Python documents in the Coda editor for Mac?

Some have said that `reindent.py` is the way to go, but it doesn't even ship with all versions of Python.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `reindent.py` from the following link: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py?revision=66903&view=markup

(Note: Original link from an old [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) comment whose reference I've lost.

Comment: Turns out I was looking for something that doesn't exist: something to reformat all indents automatically even if they're not in the right column in the first place.  Nice link for reindent though.